# I would like to ask the crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

If the record is one, I don't want to show the total qty.

If the record is more than one I want to show the total qty.

This is my crystal report design. I make the group by stock Name and Category.

You can see the detail of report design.

**Closing Balance Report**

```
 -SR0000000801      09/08/2005 1LED(Black) FlashyTouch   72  

 -SR0000000801      09/08/2005 1LED(Black) FlashyTouch    2  

                                               Total Qty 74

 -SR0000000395      06/19/2012  1x36W SurfaceType     100


                                            Total Qty 100
```

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do that on the level of C# while retreiving data from your DB
>   , if you have one record then let it be...but if more you got to pass your 
>   **"Total Qty XXX"** with the XXX value as a formula to the crystal report.

Comment: Now I'm  by using this formula "Count ({fld}, {condfld}) = 1" Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Total Qty` is displayed in group footer.

1. Create a formula `@initialize` and place it in `group header`

   `Shared NumberVar count;
   count:=0;`
2. Create one more formula now `@counting` and place in the detail part to the extreme right.

   `Shared NumberVar count;
   count:=1;
   count;`
3. Now create one more formula `@getcount`

   `Shared NumberVar count;
       sum(@count)`
4. Now in group footer where `Total Qty` was placed write supress condition.

   `if @getcount>1
   then false
   else true`

now when records are more than 1 then displayed else supressed

Comment: Thanks you so much. Now I am ok by using this formula . "Count ({fld}, {condfld}) = 1"